# How can I customize the SloppyBracletMatch background and foreground in Qscintilla PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscintilla

I was wondering how I can customize `qsci.setBraceMatching(QsciScintilla.SloppyBraceMatch)` in pyqt5 qscintilla. I already tried changing the default lexer and customizing the stylesheet but it did not work. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Customise in what way? What "did not work"?

Comment: @ekhumoro Change the foreground and background when I select matching braces in qsci

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use the following code:

```cpp
// For unmatch braces,
qsci->setUnmatchedBraceBackgroundColor (const QColor &col);
qsci->setUnmatchedBraceForegroundColor (const QColor &col);

// For matched braces,
qsci->setMatchedBraceBackgroundColor (const QColor &col);
qsci->setMatchedBraceForegroundColor (const QColor &col);
```

For Python codes,

```py
# For unmatch braces,
qsci.setUnmatchedBraceBackgroundColor(col: QColor)
qsci.setUnmatchedBraceForegroundColor(col: QColor)

# For matched braces,
qsci.setMatchedBraceBackgroundColor(col: QColor)
qsci.setMatchedBraceForegroundColor(col: QColor)
```

Please refer to https://brdocumentation.github.io/qscintilla/classQsciScintilla.html#abf85680f914ee631aa3a513ba823271f if you want to know more.